# how to remove part of a phrase from all variables in a column in R

Tags: r

say I have a Data frame

```
g <- c("Smember_1", "Smember_1", "Smember_1", "Smember_2", "Smember_2", "Smember_2", "Smember_3", "Smember_3", "Smember_3")
m <- c(1,2,1,3,4,1,3,5,6)
df <- data.frame(g, m)

     g      m
1 Smember_1 1
2 Smember_1 2
3 Smember_1 1
4 Smember_2 3
5 Smember_2 4
6 Smember_2 1
7 Smember_3 3
8 Smember_3 5
9 Smember_3 6
```

I would like to remove Smember_ in from all the variables in the g column such that the data frame df looks like

```
> df
  g m
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 1
4 2 3
5 2 4
6 2 1
7 3 3
8 3 5
9 3 6
```

Comment: gsub("([0-9]+)_.*", "\\2", df$g) that will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
df$g <- gsub(".*(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$g)
```

Comment: what if my variables run from Smember_1 to Smember_10. with your code the Smember_10 would become 0 while I would like to keep it as 10

Comment: `df2$variable <- gsub("Smember_","", df2$variable)` did the trick, thank you

Comment: That works too - might as well add as an answer to your own question. It is encouraged on SO

Answer (score 0):

> `df2$variable <- gsub("Smember_","", df2$variable)`

worked!